# Force autocorrect on a UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, autocorrect

I have a specific `UITextField` that I would like to have autocorrect in it even though the user's default is off.

Is it possible? Or do the User's setting always wins over a control?

Comment: Did you mean UITextField?

Comment: UITextField. sorry... edited...